# MBProgressHUD for Mac? - Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, hud

I'm used to the iPhone API, and I used MBProgressHUD a lot in my iPhone applications, but since I started developing apps for the Mac I noticed that I can't use MBProgressHUD. Is there an alternative that will do the same job as the MBProgressHUD? I notice that apple has it in their OS as well.
[image]

Comment: A similar question (or duplicate) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109701/create-a-temporary-hud-popup-notification-in-cocoa-app/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not `MBProgressHUD`, but you can replicate it with **[growl](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/)**.

Comment: How would I use growl in my application to produce something like that?

Comment: That link is to the Growl Developer Documents. There you will find downloads, which contains a few examples for you to start integrating into your Mac Apps.

Comment: Not sure if you still need this, but something that comes close for me is http://kdbdallas.com/2008/12/28/white-indeterminate-progress-indicator-aka-white-nsprogressindicator/

Answer (score 1):

I have recently posted on github my conversion of MBProgressHUD from iOS to OS X.
https://github.com/Foxnolds/MBProgressHUD-OSX
The MBProgressHUD class will run on iOS and OS X and will compile in ARC and Non-ARC mode.
Good luck.

Comment: This is a link only answer.